# importing other file and using functions from main

Tags: python, function, import

*Note: I have reduced my problem so the code is only a few lines (compared to 600)*

I have a problem: from `main.py` I want to import file `slave.py`. `slave.py` references a function from `main.py`, and of course I get a `NameError: name 'funcFromMain' is not defined`

Here is my code for main.py:

```
import slave

def funcFromMain():
    return 6

print(slave.funcFromSlave())
```

And here is my code for slave.py:

```
def funcFromSlave():
    one = funcFromMain() # <- this doesn't work
    two = 2
    return (one + two)
```

I am getting exact error: (note that both files are in exactly the same directory)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(slave.funcFromSlave())
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\slave.py", line 2, in funcFromSlave
    one = funcFromMain()
NameError: name 'funcFromMain' is not defined
```

I tried adding `import main` at the top of slave.py, and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import slave
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\slave.py", line 1, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(slave.funcFromSlave())
AttributeError: module 'slave' has no attribute 'funcFromSlave'
```

With `from slave import funcFromSlave` instead at the top of main:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(funcFromSlave())
  File "C:\Users\PrinceOfCreation\Documents\test\slave.py", line 2, in funcFromSlave
    one = funcFromMain()
NameError: name 'funcFromMain' is not defined
```

Comment: The only problem with your code is that `import slave.py` should be `import slave`. Other than that, there's nothing wrong with it. If this code doesn't work for you, we're gonna need more information from you - where is `slave.py` located, where is `main.py` located, what's `sys.path`, what's the output of `print(slave.__file__)`, etc.

Comment: Wait, never mind... I misunderstood the problem. Forget I said anything.

Comment: Have you tried 'import main' in slave.py? This might work, but ideally you should not have such circular dependencies in code.

Comment: Question updated: I will try @AshwineeKJha 's idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can't import a python module like this :

```
import slave.py
```

It must be

```
from slave import funcFromSlave # to get the funcFromSlave function from slave script
```

And you need to make sure that the `slave.py` is in the same directory of `main.py` or
you need to precise the subdirectory where slave.py exists

And for the later error, its best if you avoid circular imports, cause it will create problems, best to do is to send the value of `funcFromMain()` to `funcFromSlave`

main.py :

```
from slave import funcFromSlave

def funcFromMain():
    return 6

print(funcFromSlave(funcFromMain()))
```

slave.py :

```
def funcFromSlave(funcFromMain):
    one = funcFromMain
    two = 2
    return (one + two)
```

output when running main.py :

```
8
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will now attempt to apply to my other program.